# why is std::whatever::erase() a method and std::remove() a standalone function?

Tags: c++, stl

What's the difference between `erase()` and `remove()`?

- `std::whatever::erase` - takes range iterators (first-last), and matches all elements.
- `std::remove` - takes range iterators (first-last) and a value to match for removal.

Beyond that, it looks like they do the same thing. i.e. the actual 'erasure' or 'removal' is the same in both cases (unless I'm mistaken). So, why is one of them a method (of vector, set, map etc.) and the other a free-floating function?

Notes:

- Yes, I know there's also an `erase()` which takes a single iterator, but you could just as well have an `std::remove()` with the same semantics.

Comment: It is well explained on the [Erase/Remove Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) page on wikipedia.

Answer (score 7):

The erasure or removal is *not* the same.

`erase` actually removes items from a collection.

`std::remove` leaves the collection the same size as it started, but compacts the items in the collection, so those that had the value you wanted removed have been overwritten with the values after that in the collection that had other values.

In other words, if you started with `1, 2, 1, 3`, and did a `remove(..., 1)` you'd end up with a collection containing `2, 3, x, x`, where `x` signifies some unknown value (might be a moved-from value, so if they were strings they might turn into empty strings).

When it's done that, it returns an iterator to the position of the first `x`. If you want to actually delete those items from the collection, you then call `collection.erase(returned_iterator, collection.end())` (aka, the remove/erase idiom).

In case you care *why* things are this way, one reason is that `std::remove` works with iterators. An iterator allows access to elements *in* a container, but not to the surrounding container itself. As such, it's not possible for `std::remove` to erase elements from a container, even for containers that support that (and not all do).

Comment: Are these 'x' actually unspecified ?

Comment: @DieterLücking: They don't have specified values--offhand, I don't remember if they're really "unspecified" or "indeterminate". In any case, you don't know their exact value.

Answer (score 3):

`std::remove` doesn't actually destroy elements in the container. Rather, it "re*moves*" all elements satisfying specific criteria from the range and returns a past-the-end iterator for the new end of the range.

> Removing is done by shifting (by means of move assignment) the
>   elements in the range in such a way that the elements that are not to
>   be removed appear in the beginning of the range. Relative order of the
>   elements that remain is preserved and the physical size of the
>   container is unchanged. - http://en.cppreference.com/

Move-assignment leaves the moved variable in a valid but unspecified state, so it may or may not be left unchanged.

To actually delete elements from the container, you need to call `erase`.

Here is a concrete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void printVector( const std::vector<int>& v )
{
    for ( auto i : v ) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4 };

    printVector( v ); // Prints 0 1 2 1 3 4

    // Shift elemnts that aren't to be removed to the beginning of container
    const auto newEnd = std::remove( v.begin(), v.end(), 1 );

    printVector( v ); // Prints 0 2 3 4 * *

    // Erase the unwanted elements
    v.erase( newEnd, v.end() );

    printVector( v ); // Prints 0 2 3 4

    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://rextester.com/WZRZ55603)

Answer (score 1):

`std::remove` (and `std::remove_if`) is a general purpose algorithm that can be applied (also) to arrays. Elements of arrays can not be erased. Sizes of arrays are fixed. You only can move "erased" elements in an array to its tail. And arrays do not have methods. You can use only general functions with arrays.

Method `erase` of user defined (that is of standard) containers indeed erases elements of a container. Moreover this method does unconditional erasing of elements.

Take into account that to erase elements from a container you need to know the implementation details of the container. So this explains why erase is defined as a method of containers.

In turn standard algorithms `std::remove` and `std::remove_if`  implement a general algorithm of moving "erased" elements. They need not to know the implementation details of the container to which they are apllied.

Besides method erase classes `std::list` and `std::forward_list` also have their own methods `remove` and `remove_if` that opposite to the general algorithms `std::remove` and `std::remove_if` erase elements from lists according to some conditions (similarly to standard algorithms `std::remove` and `std::remove_if`).

Consider the following example that to see the difference between general algorithm `std::remove` and method `remove` of class `std::list`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

int main() 
{
    std::list<int> l = { 1, 10, 2, 3, 10, 4 };

    std::cout << "size of the list is " << l.size() << std::endl;
    for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;     

    std::remove( l.begin(), l.end(), 10 );

    std::cout << "\nsize of the list is " << l.size() << std::endl;
    for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;     

    l = { 1, 10, 2, 3, 10, 4 };

    l.remove( 10 );

    std::cout << "\nsize of the list is " << l.size() << std::endl;
    for ( int x : l ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;     

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
size of the list is 6
1 10 2 3 10 4

size of the list is 6
1 2 3 4 10 4 

size of the list is 4
1 2 3 4
```